# Stuck on a limits mixed of integral and functions

Tags: limits, multivariable-calculus

$f(x,y)$ is continuous on $D=\{(x,y)\mid 0\le x,y\le1\}$ and is differentiable at point$(0,0)$ , $f(0,0)=0$, $f'_y(0,0)=1$.

Calculate the following limits.
$$I=\lim_{x\rightarrow0^+}{\frac{\int_0^{x^2}dt\int_x^{\sqrt{t}}f(t,u)du}{x\sin^{-1}(x)-x^2}}$$
This is how far I go.In the denominator, as $x\to0^+$,
$$x\sin^{-1}(x)-x^2=\frac{x^4}{6}+o(x^4)$$
In the numerator, change order of $dt$ and $du$ and using L'Hospital's rule I get $$I=\lim_{x\to0^+}\frac{-\int_0^x\int_0^{u^2}f(t,u)dtsu}{x^4/6}=-\frac32\lim_{x\to0^+}\frac{\int_0^{x^2}f(t,x)dt}{x^3}$$ and I stuck there. What shall I do next or any new ideas?